# Approaches to manage property files In production environment

Tags: spring, maven, deployment, properties, production-environment

I would like to get your ideas about what’s  the best way to manage property files  shared across the projects  .

Consider we have Four application – Application1 , Application2 Application3 and Application4 – All Application are deployed on **same Box**

Consider We have below property files

1. File1.property  -- used in   Application1 , Application2
   Application3 and Application4
2. File2.property  -- used in   Application1 , Application2
3. File3.property  -- used in   Application2  Application3
4. File4.property  -- used in   Application1 , Application4
5. File5.property  -- used in   Application3
6. File6.property -- used   in  Application4

Number of Property files might increase in future.

Currently I am considering below approaches

**Approach 1** – Bundles all required property file in individual jar. 
Cons –  1 :  property files are repeating in multiple projects 
      2 : Need more efforts to make sure all property files are in syn in all projects.

**Approach 2 :** create separate bundle of all property files in separate project ,Deploy this project as configuration project.
Point some environment variable to this location and in java code load property files from this location.

Is it good idea ?

Comment: Do you need to really share the property files or only a kind of configuration which can be offered by an appropriate class ?

Comment: property files have information about the environment,configuration , paths etc. need to be same/consistence   for all projects

Comment: Which can be implemented by a class in a single jar file which offers an appropriate interface which loads the property file...by that you can simply share configuration information over different modules...

Comment: loading property file is not a problem, All are spring base application so using single line  @PropertySource i am loading all my properties. my concern how should i bundle my common propriety files

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is not clear from your question is whether the filed that you are proposing to deploy contain the actual production properties, or whether they are just templates that some / something is going to update when the applications are deployed.

Or to put it another way, whether you have a clean conceptual separation between software development, testing and production.  Assuming that you do, then you will most likely find that:

- each "deployment" will need its own set of properties,
- the production deployment will most likely require version control *distinct from version control of the application*,
- the life-cycle for the production configs will most likely need to be different to the application life-cycle.

Or at least, that is how large scale apps are typically handled in large organisations where "development" and "operations" are distinct responsibilities.  (In a dev-ops world, there is value in separating the life-cycles of the application and the configuration, even if the "dev" and "ops" tasks are performed by the same people.)

Here are a couple more ideas:

- If the applications are intended to be deployed on end-user machines, it is advisable to integrate the properties into some kind of preference management framework.
- Under some circumstances, it could be better to use ".ini" files rather than class (or XML) Java properties files.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for checking this. Yes i do have separate properties for dev ,testing and prod. currently i am using approach 2 mentioned in quotation . i am creating 3 different bundle (dev,testing,prod) of configuration and managing  versions  using maven. each config  bundle is getting deployed in it's  corresponding environment.